# grub openup everytime of start of pc,how to stop that?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, upgrade, 20.04

whenever start computer the grub terminal opens up.But i dont want that to happen every time .how would i stop it from comming everytime.(which option should i change in the grub config file if that is what it needed to be done to stop it).os version ubuntu 20.
this is the grub config file.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: is it a dual boot?

Comment: what is the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` command in the terminal..

Comment: What do you mean by "opens up"? What does it say on screen?

Comment: not a dual boot , i meant grub terminal comes up when booting

Comment: @PRATAP i put the code in the question,and i have changed some values but didnt have any change

Comment: So did you run `sudo update-grub` after editing `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: @rickymorty try this one.. https://askubuntu.com/q/1239903/739431

Comment: @mook765 yes, i have changed GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 to 2 was that suppose to mak a difference

Comment: k @ PRATAP ,wll try this https://askubuntu.com/q/1239903/739431 thanks

Comment: @Soren A  the grub terminal gui comes up