# How do I skip grub and boot directly to Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239903/how-to-disable-grub-menu-at-boot-time-in-ubuntu-20-04) -- that question deals with a dual-boot situation.

---

I have a completely stock install of Ubuntu 20.04 (on a Thinkpad p1 gen 2) on my main hard drive / boot device, and no other operating systems. When I power on the laptop and do nothing else, it boots to a grub menu, where the default option is to boot Ubuntu.

I would like to skip the grub menu and boot Ubuntu directly. My (stock) `/etc/default/grub` file looks like:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: @karel no, the answers in that question don't solve the problem in this case. I don't know if this is specific to 20.04 but it might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

to your `/etc/default/grub` (`sudo` is required to edit it) and then run `sudo update-grub`.

Simply reboot and the system should boot Ubuntu directly without pausing at the grub menu.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/gc9a3w/how_to_disable_grub_menu_on_2004/fpd02gc/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: Oddly, that didn't work in my Kubuntu 23.10 (dev). But the old solution of setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT=` worked , although letting a sec or two is more reasonable in case of problems, when one might need to use another kernel.